# SQL Server: update five columns with one condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

In a table, I have a column for currency. I have to calculate a value from two columns (ex: a, b) and update one of the five columns (ex: e, f, g, h, i, j) based on the currency.

I tried with CASE like

```
CASE when currency = 'INR'
then a+b
else 0
end as e
CASE when currency = 'USD'
then a+b
else 0
end as f
CASE when currency = 'CAN'
then a+b
else 0
end as g
CASE when currency = 'EUR'
then a+b
else 0
end as h
CASE when currency = 'AUD'
then a+b
else 0
end as i
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
Update myTable
   set e = CASE when currency = 'INR' then a+b ELSE 0 end, 
       f = CASE when currency = 'USD' then a+b ELSE 0 end,
       g = CASE when currency = 'CAN' then a+b ELSE 0 end,
       h = CASE when currency = 'EUR' then a+b ELSE 0 end,
       i = CASE when currency = 'AUD' then a+b ELSE 0 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code would be like following.
NULL / 0 values are not covered.

```
    var result = a+b;
    var columnName;

    CASE
    WHEN currency = 'INR' THEN columnName = e,
    WHEN currency = 'USD' THEN columnName = f,
    .
    .

    WHEN currency = 'AUD' THEN columnName = j

    END


    **your update statement goes here with 'columnName' variable..**
```

Comment: Is it possible to do other than the CASE statement?

Comment: @VigneshVelusamy, yes. You can use 'if else' ladder to form sql query.